# POSTGRESQL - DJANGO - time without time zone en date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I'm working on a project's Django with a Postegresql database.

I just created a model like that :

```
from django.db import models

from members.models import CustomUser


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to migrate, I've this issue :
ERREUR:  can't convert type time without time zone en date

In my DB, I've in my table "time without time zone".

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField`, `DateField` does not store timezone.

Read the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

This might help:

```
from django.db import models

from members.models import CustomUser


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True) # --> changed to DateField
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True) # --> changed to DateField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi ! DateTime ? Isn't in the models... DateFields yes but this is the same issue.

Comment: @ValentinBocquet oh, sorry for typo, I mean to datefield only

Comment: @ValentinBocquet can we edit something in database?

Comment: Yes of course. DateField or DateTime return the same issue. I deleted the database and recreate it.